# Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient

Tags: entity-framework

I have an exeption
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.'

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
 {
      cmd.Connection = connection;
      connection.Open();

      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                    return true;
               }                              
      }
  }
```

}

[My CSProj file who contain all references of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAAix.png)

[Exeption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwvJw.png)

Comment: Please describe your issue, tag correct technologies and share some code if it causes the ussie.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community the problem is solved
I added the dll Microsoft.Data.SqlClient with same version to the exe program which calls my c# library which contains Microsoft.Data.SqlClient same version 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved
I added the dll Microsoft.Data.SqlClient with same version to the exe program which calls my c# library which contains Microsoft.Data.SqlClient same version 4.1.0