Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient Error - How to Resolve Platform Compatibility Issue?
I'm encountering an error with the message

Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient

while working on my application. The error suggests that a certain feature or component related to SQL Client is not supported on my current platform.
Here are some details about my setup:
Platform: Windows 10
SQL Client Library: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Version of SQL Client Library: 2.1.7
Framework/Runtime: .NET STANDARD 2.0

I have already tried the following steps:
Updated Dependencies: I ensured that all dependencies are up-to-date.
Checked Configuration: Verified that all configuration settings are correctly applied.

.NET Standard is not a runtime - it is just an API filter (give or take). So: what is the actual runtime that your application (the executable or web-site) is targeting? .NET Framework 4.8? .NET 8.0? Something else? Also: any notable features that you're trying to use? Perhaps ambient transactions (TransactionScope)? or a specific TLS version? column level encryption? And is there a stacktrace we can see that might help us identify a feature?

Share more details about your context and scenario and when are you getting this error message? Include the relevant code snippet which throwing this error.

@MdFaridUddinKiron I created a library using .NET Standard 2.0 to be accessed from .NET Framework 4.8. The problem arises when I call the library; that exception is thrown. The code in the library simply opens a connection using the SqlConnection class from the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient'

Would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563726/strings-platformnotsupported-datasqlclient

@Renat I tried it, but it didn’t work.

I'll repeat: .NET Standard is not a runtime. What runtime does the application target (what the library targets is not all that relevant). Is there a stacktrace we can see? You say this occurs when opening the connection; can we see that? is it literally throwing on conn.Open(); ? or await conn.OpenAsync();? Can we see a sanitized version of the connection string (we don't need your passwords, etc), to see if there's anything relevant there? is this talking to a local SQL server, or a cloud hosted server? We'd love to help you, but we need context.

@MarcGravell I reference the library project from a .NET Framework 4.8 project. It fails when SqlConnection reads the connection string.

Great; and I say again: can we see a stacktrace? is there anything non-trivial in the connection-string? are you using any features like TransactionScope, etc?

@Ruben so you didn't even try to open it yet? just the new(connectionstring) is sufficient to throw the error? I want to be 100% clear here. And can we please see the stacktrace when this happens? (a stacktrace is the single most useful tool for diagnosing any issue)

Can I clarify: you say "Version of SQL Client Library: 2.1.7" and you also say "I ensured that all dependencies are up-to-date", but the current version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is 5.2.1 (which includes netfx support); 2.1.7 is ... well, it isn't super old (6 months), but it feels like using 5.2.1 might be the first thing to try

@MarcGravell
`System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient'
``
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.SqlConnection(string)
DBLibDapper.DBLibDapper.AbreDataSet(string, string, System.Data.DataSet, bool) en DBLibDapper.cs
DBLib.TtoDatos.AbreDataSet(string, string, System.Data.DataSet, bool) en DBLib.cs
XMDI.MainWindow.CargarSubmenuPadres() en XMDI.cs
XMDI.MainWindow.MainWindow() en XMDI.cs`

@MarcGravell At first, I tried using version 5.2.1, but it seems to be incompatible with my .NET Framework version, as it threw a compatibility exception.

@MarcGravell This is what i have when I try to use 5.2.1:
`
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.'
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.SqlConnection(string)
DBLibDapper.DBLibDapper.AbreDataSet(string, string, System.Data.DataSet, bool) en DBLibDapper.cs
DBLib.TtoDatos.AbreDataSet(string, string, System.Data.DataSet, bool) en DBLib.cs
XMDI.MainWindow.CargarSubmenuPadres() en XMDI.cs
XMDI.MainWindow.MainWindow() en XMDI.cs
`

This is very odd, and seems unexpected. Does System.Data.SqlClient work?

With System.Data.SqlClient:
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.'

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#11-why-do-i-get-a-platformnotsupported-exception-when-my-application-hits-a-sqlclient-method might be useful; I wonder, however, whether changing the library from netstandard2.0 to net48 might improve things
